# How to log exceptions with network targets in NLog

Tags: exception, networking, stack-trace, nlog, sentinel

I am using the [NLog](http://nlog-project.org) logging framework and am trying to get exception and stacktrace information showing up in any UDP logger appliaction, such as [Sentinel](http://sentinel.codeplex.com/) and [Log2Console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/), but can only get the log message part displayed. Outputting to a file works well as most examples do just that, so the problem revolves around using network targets with NLog.

Bonus if a custom format can be applied on inner exceptions and stacktrace, but this is not required. Exception.ToString() would go a long way.

Note on the example code: With [Log2Console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/) I found an [article](http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/How-to-send-stacktrace-of-exceptions-to-Chainsaw-or-Log2Console-td5465045.html) on how to send exception as a separate log entry. Although this worked, I was not happy with the solution.

**Example exception logging code:**

```
Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

try
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("My ex", new FileNotFoundException("My inner ex1", new AccessViolationException("Innermost ex")));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.ErrorException("TEST", e);
}
```

**Example NLog.config:**

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<targets async="true">

    <!-- Send by UDP to Sentinel with NLogViewer protocol -->
    <target name="network" xsi:type="NLogViewer" address="udp://192.168.1.3:9999" layout="${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}" />

    <!-- Send message by UDP to Log2Console with Chainsaw protocol -->
    <target name="network2" xsi:type="Chainsaw" address="udp://192.168.1.3:9998" appinfo="Grocelist"/>

    <!-- Send exception/stacktrace by UDP to Log2Console with generic network protocol -->
    <target name="network2ex" xsi:type="Network" address="udp4://192.168.1.3:9998" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />

    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
                createDirs="true"
                fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
                />
</targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="network" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="network2" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="network2ex" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Some links:**

- http://nlog-project.org
- http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Targets
- http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Exception_layout_renderer
- http://nlog-project.org/2011/04/20/exception-logging-enhancements.html
- http://nlog-project.org/wiki/How_to_properly_log_exceptions%3F
- [How to tell NLog to log exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199073/how-to-tell-nlog-to-log-exceptions)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9684111/134761
- http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/How-to-send-stacktrace-of-exceptions-to-Chainsaw-or-Log2Console-td5465045.html

**Edit:**
After searching some more this seems to be a limitation on NLog's end. A recent patch is apparently out there: [log4jxmlevent does not render Exception](http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/6777)

**Edit2:**
I rebuilt NLog with patch, but it did not seem to help in Sentinel or Log2Console apps. I might have to try log4net to make sure those apps really do support what I am trying to achieve.

**Edit3:**
I currently use string.Format() to join and format message and exception text myself. This works well, but is not what I'm looking for here.

Comment: The source code for NLogViewerTarget on Github shows that the Layout set {} is no-op so you cannot override the default which does not include exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

You can also extend NLog to include exceptions for network logging.

Create an extended layout:

```
[Layout("Log4JXmlEventLayoutEx")]    
public class Log4JXmlEventLayoutEx : Log4JXmlEventLayout
{
    protected override string GetFormattedMessage(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        string msg = logEvent.Message + " ${exception:format=Message,Type,ToString,StackTrace}";
        msg = SimpleLayout.Evaluate(msg, logEvent);    
        LogEventInfo updatedInfo;
        if (msg == logEvent.Message) { 
            updatedInfo = logEvent;
        } else {
            updatedInfo = new LogEventInfo(
                logEvent.Level, logEvent.LoggerName, 
                logEvent.FormatProvider, msg, 
                logEvent.Parameters, logEvent.Exception);
        }    
        return base.GetFormattedMessage(updatedInfo);
    }
}
```

Create a target that uses that layout

```
[Target("NLogViewerEx")]
public class NLogViewerTargetEx : NLogViewerTarget
{
    private readonly Log4JXmlEventLayoutEx layout = new Log4JXmlEventLayoutEx();    
    public override Layout Layout { get { return layout; } set {} }
}
```

Update NLog.config:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Assembly.Name.That.Contains.Extended.Target"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="logViewer" 
            xsi:type="NLogViewerEx" 
            address="udp://localhost:7071">
  </targets>
 ...
</nlog>
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution!

Comment: Hi Alex, is it possible to have two custom Layouts for two targets? `Sentinel` and `File ? I'm stuck and it is not working (https://stackoverflow.com/q/47753773/6229375) - (link updated).

Answer (score 3):

A few years later and this is pretty trivial, try adding

> includeSourceInfo="true"

to your target file, so it looks like;

```
 <target name="viewer"
            xsi:type="NLogViewer"
            includeSourceInfo="true"
            address="udp://127.0.0.1:9999" />
```

Gives you Source File, Line, Class and Method info.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this the next time I come across NLog and UDP again.

Comment: Sadly still no easy way of getting a stacktrace though! And running in Release mode strips a lot of the source info.. I'd avoid this approach a bit longer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and just updated my NLog nuget package to 2.0.1.2

Now I have exceptions coming through to Log2Console just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll have to revisit this sometime and try it myself! Could you also post your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw?  It will display stack traces and supports log4net/UDP appenders, and according to NLog you can use it as well:
http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Chainsaw_target

Try the latest developer snapshot, has a ton of features: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: I feel bad, but I can't seem to figure out how to run the latest snapshot on Windows? The zip file only contains a .bat, and by reading it I can't figure out exactly what I need to do to get it working.

Comment: You need to have a Java runtime installed.  Once you do, you can save the zip to your file system and extract it, navigate to the apache-chainsaw-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT\bin folder and run the chainsaw.bat command. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just download and build the latest (NLog-Build-2.0.0.2007-0-g72f6495) sources from GitHub: https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/tree/
This issue is fixed there by NLog developer.

Comment: You can also download compiled binaries from here http://nlog.codeplex.com/releases/view/81084

Answer (score 1):

In your NLog.config modify the target like the following.

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="log.txt" layout="${longdate}:${message} ${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*}" />
```

The part that you are looking for is

```
${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*}
```

For more information on this look [here](http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/09/24/Logging-exceptions-with-NLog.aspx).

Comment: This is for file target only, right? The question was to get exception information for network targets.

Comment: Ahh, I must have just missed that.  Yes this is for outputting to a file. GL getting a network solution.